# php -v and phpinfo(); returns different versions

Tags: apache2, php

I want to use php 8.1 on Ubuntu server
Currently it works with php 7.4.30

```
lsb_release -a
```

returns

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I followed tutorials and so I executed these commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.1
sudo apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-mysql php8.1-zip php8.1-gd php8.1-mbstring php8.1-curl php8.1-xml php8.1-bcmath
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now when I do `php -v` I see:

```
PHP 8.1.18 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2023 04:39:07) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.18, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.18, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

when I do

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php

 Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        manual mode
```

Same for `sudo update-alternatives --config phar` and `sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar`
, php 8.1 is selected.

However, my application (a CMS) is still in php 7.4
I also tested with a simple php file with `phpinfo();`

What else can I check?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April with 5 years of *standard* supported life; you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm the life remaining...  It was extended by 1 month by Canonical for some architectures, but I'd suggest planning for your *release-upgrade* asap.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for the info. I did not know. I'm a web developer and not a server expert. Is it possible that my php version problem comes from my Ubuntu obsolete version?

Comment: I'm not seeing any `sudo a2enmod php8.1` in there ... 

Comment: @matigo I thought select php version with `sudo update-alternatives --config php` could be used instead of `a2enmod php8.1`, this is not the case?

Comment: PHP CLI != Apache PHP 

Comment: what matigo said: the 2 are not the same :) "However, my application (a CMS) is still in php 7.4 I also tested with a simple php file with phpinfo();" you need a newer apache ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, the solution was indeed `sudo a2dismod php7.4` + `sudo a2enmod php8.1` If someone want to post the solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP CLI is not the same as the PHP Apache module.

[See this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/971895#971895) for more informations

So the solution is to tell Apache to use the installed version of PHP 8.1 by disabling the old PHP module and enabling the new PHP module using the following command.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll need to check php.ini.

In phpinfo() page, you will see which php.ini your web server is using.
If you're seeing 7.4, probably your php.ini path would be something like:

.../7.4/apache2/php.ini

Just find the php.ini file for your php v8.1 installation and change the settings in your web server so it points to it.